# Need help displaying the contents of a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

http://jsfiddle.net/hbrennan72/0urqaee9/

I have taken a very simple W3Schools JSON example and modified it ever so slightly.  I am having trouble displaying just the contents contents of the JSON file.  The external JSON file is referenced in the JS but I also copied the contents into the CSS frame on JSFiddle.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://schwartzcomputer.com/ICT4570/Resources/USPresidents.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + 
        arr[i].president + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "having trouble displaying it"? Do you mean referencing the properties in the object?

Comment: Yes, I want to display the full contents of the JSON file in a table on a separate web page.

Comment: The response is not in array format, it's object, so you don't get `length` property of it. Your looping use `length` that make it loop nothing because `arr.length` is undefined. Are you sure you get the right data?

Comment: Yes the data in the JSON file is accurate if that's what you mean.

Comment: Here is a different example I am working on:  http://jsfiddle.net/hbrennan72/0urqaee9/7/

Comment: You actually need to iterate through arr.presidents, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript for more pointers, because president is basically a collection of presidents. See what you get when you do arr.presidents.president[0].term.

Answer (score 0):

For the XML references, ex. xmlns:xsi, you will need to use bracket notation. You can reference the presidents list objects as you would any JavaSscript object.

Forked [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vh29daqh/)

You can display the properties in any format you like.

```
function myFunction(arr) {
    alert(arr.presidents["xmlns:xsi"]);
    alert(arr.presidents.president[0].number + ". " + arr.presidents.president[0].name);
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

I have amended the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epj4w1zg/) to create a table. I did not include all the fields you specified, but will get the general idea.

Comment: Erm, are you sure it has anything to do with the xml namespace and not the fact that it is a collection of presidents called president?

Comment: I am looking to something like this:  http://www.w3schools.com/json/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_server_sql_style

Comment: Ok I almost have it where it displays the full list of US presidents:  http://jsfiddle.net/hbrennan72/0urqaee9/52/

Comment: Thanks for your help Ron!  I reapply appreciate it.  Now I can't figure out the header.  Probably something simple but heck if I know...http://jsfiddle.net/hbrennan72/0urqaee9/90/

Comment: It appears above every record vs. just the first one.

Comment: You just need to move the header columns outside of the loop - jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s9zyacq9/ - you can also replace the "td" tags with "th" and remove the "b" tags since "th" tags are centered and bold.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through arr.presidents.president

```
function myFunction(arr) {
var out = "";
var i;
for(i = 0; i < arr.presidents.president.length; i++) {
    out += JSON.stringify(arr.presidents.president[i]) + '</a><br>';
}
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks!  That displays the contents of the JSON file.    http://jsfiddle.net/hbrennan72/0urqaee9/10/However, Now I want to make it "pretty".  I am guessing I need to set up some kind of a table (even though I have read tables are frowned on in HTML5)

Comment: That is a different question. @Hermenegida, are you going to explain why, as I did in my comment saying the same thing?

Comment: More specifically, I want to only display the number, name, birthday, took office and left office elements as columns in a table.

Comment: Ok, So now I am having trouble with something that is probably simple.  I want to display the table header once at the top but it keeps repeating for each element. Any thoughts?   http://jsfiddle.net/hbrennan72/0urqaee9/89/

Comment: You have to move the table header outside the loop.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help!  Now I am having trouble displaying just the vice president in a separate table.  I keep getting undefined errors for the name of each vp.

Comment: The JSON file is located here: http://schwartzcomputer.com/ICT4570/Resources/USPresidents.json  I used JSONLint to verify the data and make it more presentable...

Comment: So some entries have one president but 2 vps.  I am trying to get both VPs to show for one prez.  See http://jsfiddle.net/0urqaee9/112/ CSS frame for JSON snipplet.                                         .out +=
"<tr><td>" + arr.presidents.president[i].number + "</td>" +
"<td>" + arr.presidents.president[i].term.vice_president + "</td></tr>";
}

Comment: So if arr.presidents.president[i].term isArray [see link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) then you have to iterate through `arr.presidents.president[i].term[j]`

Comment: I have added var j; but am receiving the following error message in the console: arr.presidents.president[i].term[j] is undefined